# how to sent the whole div data to the next result page through php or javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web page having Menu and in Menu each element having check box. the user are allowed to check or uncheck the element. when i it finalized through submit button, i want to sent the check elements to the next result page. i am attaching screen shots of before and after to understand the scenario.if code are required then i will sent you.

```
[![This is Header having check boxes][1]][1]
[![Some check box are unchecked][2]][2]
[![This is the finalized requirements from user side][3]][3]
```

Comment: Using post or session

Comment: So you want them to click your checkboxes, make the clicked items appear on the next page? Can u pls show some more code/input/output or the error ?

Comment: sent me address and i will sent you the file then you would be better understand what i want

Comment: sent me your email and i will sent you the whole file then you will better understand what i want

Comment: zakirkhan90089@gmial.com

Answer (score 0):

Is the form tag that what you're looking for?

all input tag `<input>` should be automatically sent to another page by submit button inside form tag `<form></form>` [Click here to learn more](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)

Comment: No dear it just sent a few elements and i want to sent the whole page having hundreds elements like home,about us, contact us, login links and the whole body etc

Comment: i have five buttons in my project. i want to use one back button. With the help of the back button i should back to the recent page from where i came yet.                                                                                         
code of jQuery ... ...

       Code
      $("#back").click(function(e) 
     e.preventDefault();
    $("iframe").attr('src',"loginTumbnail.html");
    });
    Inline image 1

when i click on button button it should come back to that page from where i recently come